# mysql query scanning all rows

Tags: mysql, rows, database-scan

Guys trying to wrap my head around mysql query on why it is scanning all rows in table

I have 2 tables topic_entry and topic_user

```
CREATE TABLE `topic_entry` (
  `entry_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `topic_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `entry_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `entry_object` text,
  `level` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '3',
  PRIMARY KEY (`entry_id`),
  KEY `entry_created` (`entry_created`),
  KEY `level` (`level`),
  KEY `topic_id_2` (`topic_id`,`entry_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

CREATE TABLE `topic_user` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `topic_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `private` enum('y','n') DEFAULT NULL,
  `freq` enum('a','d','w') DEFAULT NULL,
  `topic_id_freq` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `casematch` enum('0','1') DEFAULT '0',
  `textmatch` enum('0','1') DEFAULT '0',
  `topic_name_case` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `topic_id_user_id` (`topic_id`,`user_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `topic_id_freq` (`topic_id_freq`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

This is the query that i am trying to run

```
explain 
select  te.topic_id,te.entry_id 
from topic_entry te 
WHERE te.topic_id in (select topic_id 
                        from topic_user where user_id ='xyz') 
    AND te.level=4 
    AND te.entry_id > 0 
ORDER BY te.entry_id DESC 
LIMIT 5;
```

The explain output shows that it is scanning all rows

```
|  1 | PRIMARY| te | range  | PRIMARY,level | PRIMARY | 8 | NULL| **722978** | Using where              | 
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | topic_user | unique_subquery | topic_id_user_id,user_id | topic_id_user_id | 310     | func,const |      1 | Using index; Using where |
```

Comment: Any pointers as to how the scan can be avoided

Comment: It has to scan to fulfill the where conditions. You may need to create some indexes on user_id and level and entry_id as a start, to see if it will do an index scan instead of a sequential scan.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT      te.topic_id,te.entry_id 
FROM        topic_entry te 
JOIN        topic_user tu ON te.topic_id = tu.topic_id AND tu.user_id = 'xyz'
WHERE       te.level=4 
AND         te.entry_id > 0 
ORDER BY    te.entry_id DESC 
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: tried join before, with this join it does temporary filesort, which is also slow

Comment: Ok, just thought it may help, I created a test schema and using your code created the same tables, but without the data, was unable to accurately test the query on my end.

Comment: The problem may be that you have, in both tables, a key comprised of two columns and no foreign relationship set.

Comment: Also wanted to throw this out there.  Start with a basic query in your explain and see what it outputs and then slowly add your join and where clauses one at a time to see at what point it changes drastically.

Comment: in the above query if i remove the order by clause, it works perfect. So something with order by clause not using the index properly

Comment: I'm confused about one thing, why are you using a where clause of 'te.entry_id > 0' if that column is unsigned because all entries will be greater than 0 (unless of course you have a zeroth entry).

Comment: that was just for historic reasons, i've removed that condition, its still the same. I have composite index of topic_id,entry_id   . The tables are being joined on topic_id  so technically for ordering by entry_id it should index

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the sequence of keys in your WHERE clause:
`WHERE te.topic_id in (select topic_id from topic_user where user_id ='xyz') AND te.level=4 AND te.entry_id > 0`
to
`WHERE te.topic_id in (select topic_id from topic_user where user_id ='xyz') AND te.entry_id > 0 AND te.level=4`
I am not 100% sure (and I can not test it at the moment) but it may help.
The reason being that MySQL tries and fails to map your keys
`topic_id, level, entry_id` to `KEY topic_id_2` and fails because of the extra field.

P.S. and "Sly Raskal" has even better solution, or you can try to combine both

Comment: no difference on changing the sequence of keys. not sure but may be the preprocessor takes care of the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
explain extended
select  te.topic_id,te.entry_id 
from topic_entry te LEFT JOIN topic_user tu ON
    te.topic_id = tu.topic_id AND tu.user_id = 'xyz'
WHERE 1 = 1
    AND te.level=4 
    AND te.entry_id > 0 
ORDER BY te.entry_id DESC 
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: less than 1% difference in the # of rows scanned, when using the above query

Comment: @user1590071, you don't have referential constraint (because of myisam) and also, I don;t have your data.BTW, explain plain said something different then you.